# Check if any row of CSV file has integer or string

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have a csv file:
[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfqQX.png)

Currently my code looks like this:

```
namespace AzureFunctionTest
{

    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function started at: {DateTime.Now}");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function completed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            var path = @"C:\Users\sandurpr\.......\COA-Blanket-TB.csv";
            string csvData = File.ReadAllText(path);
            Console.WriteLine(csvData);
```

I want to be able to accomplish the logic where the user **inputs row and column value** and when he clicks enter it says if the corresponding value is an **integer or string**

Comment: Hi User - 
You should show us your attempt, show us a specific error where we can assist you, general advice on how to do stuff, is a different stack I believe. 

But I can hint that it will likely involve the "IsDigit()" method, and a string parse.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to accomplish the logic where the user inputs row and column value and when he clicks enter it says if the corresponding value is an integer or string

Your function runs on timed events (every 5 minutes if I recalled that Cron syntax correctly), thus independently of any user interaction. In order to run this on user input, you could implement the function with a [`HttpTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp) and call it via a web frontend (since you'd have to host it somewhere else, you'll have to set up [CORS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/handling-cors-in-azure-function/) in order to make it work).

The web frontend would gather all the user input and then pass it to the function via the HTTP trigger.